# AutoHotkey V2: Write and store clipboard to variable script not working

Tags: autohotkey, clipboard

I'm trying to write a script to store the value of the current clipboard to a variable, where I can do this with multiple variables.

The idea is that I can "paste" multiple pieces of text by storing them to multiple variables with clipboard.

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

varNumpadEnd    := "1"
varNumpadDown   := "2"
varNumpadPgDn   := "3"

^NumpadEnd::{
    A_Clipboard := ""
    Send "^c"
    ClipWait
    varNumpadEnd := A_Clipboard
}

NumpadEnd::{
    Send varNumpadEnd
}
NumpadDown::{
    Send varNumpadDown
}
NumpadPgDn::{
    Send varNumpadPgDn
}
```

The script doesn't seem to be updating the variables.
When I press ^NumpadEnd the script does copy the selected text, I know this because when I press ctrl + v it does paste the previously selected text.

However, when I press NumpadEnd, it will always "paste" "1".

Help would be appreciated, it seems to me that the script is unable to update the variable (maybe it's a scope issue?).

I tried to remove the variable declaration on the top, but I would be faced with error when starting the script, stating that the variables have not been assigned a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that this is not working is that in v2 all hotkeys are treated as a function and so all variables within the braces are local. You can achieve your desired effect without creating global variables like this:

```
*NumpadEnd:: {
    static varNumpadEnd := 1

    if (GetKeyState("Ctrl", "P")) {
        old := A_Clipboard
        A_Clipboard := ""

        Send("^c")
        ClipWait

        varNumpadEnd := A_Clipboard
        A_Clipboard := old
    }
    else {
        old := A_Clipboard
        A_Clipboard := ""

        A_Clipboard := varNumpadEnd
        ClipWait

        Send("^v")

        Sleep(100)
        A_Clipboard := old
    }
}
```

And if you want to combine all three:

```
*NumpadEnd::
*NumpadDown::
*NumpadPgDn:: {
    static varNumpadEnd := 1, varNumpadDown := 2, varNumpadPgDn := 3

    static __Strip(keyName) {
        return (RegExReplace(keyName, "[~*$+^! &]|AppsKey"))
    }

    if (GetKeyState("Ctrl", "P")) {
        old := A_Clipboard
        A_Clipboard := ""

        Send("^c")
        ClipWait

        var%__Strip(A_ThisHotkey)% := A_Clipboard
        A_Clipboard := old
    }
    else {
        old := A_Clipboard
        A_Clipboard := ""

        A_Clipboard := var%__Strip(A_ThisHotkey)%
        ClipWait

        Send("^v")

        Sleep(100)
        A_Clipboard := old
    }
}
```

The hotkey names (NumpadEnd, NumpadDown, ...) must match up with the static var names (varNumpadEnd, varNumpadDown, ...) for it to dereference `A_ThisHotkey` properly.

Comment: This works, thanks!

If it's not too much, could you elaborate roughly what the following part of the script does?

`static __Strip(keyName) {return (RegExReplace(keyName, "[~*$+^! &]|AppsKey"))}`

I'm also a little bit confused by the `else` part of the script, what exactly does it do?

Comment: `__Strip(keyName)` will return the hotkey (example: *NumpadEnd) with the modifiers stripped (example: !NumpadEnd -> NumpadEnd). This is necessary because the static variables are named without any modifiers. You can achieve this with substring also but the function makes the code configurable, it will still work if you change the hotkeys to some other combination of keys.

The `else` part is code to run if the hotkey was pressed without the ctrl modifier.